# Implementing a basic RWLock like structure with only using Atomic primitives

Tags: multithreading, rust, locking, atomic

I have the need for a basic locking mechanism for my data structure. It needs to support high thread read contention and being writer sided. So if a writer wants to write it blocks all further threads from reading until the write happened. In my environment there is no allocator available so I am limited to stack and static variables.
A writer thread gets created when a reader thread detects some specific conditions. The write function doesn't actually write any new data but reorders the old structure to speed up further reading. That's why when one write is already "fixing" the structure new writers don't need to do anything.

This is the writer function:

```rust
static active_thread_counter: AtomicI64 = AtomicI64::new(0);
const writer_sign_num: i64 = 0x100_0000_0000;

unsafe fn write() {
    //signal writer is waiting
    let thread_counter = active_thread_counter.fetch_sub(writer_sign_num, Ordering::SeqCst);

    if thread_counter < 0 {
        //if there is already a writer waiting remove the signal of this thread
        active_thread_counter.fetch_add(writer_sign_num, Ordering::SeqCst);
        return;
    }

    //wait for all readers to have finished 
    while !(active_thread_counter.load(Ordering::SeqCst) == -writer_sign_num) {
        sleep(Duration::new(0, 1000));
    }

    //write stuff here

    //open lock again (should be 0 after this operation)
    active_thread_counter.fetch_add(writer_sign_num, Ordering::SeqCst);
}
```

The idea is to signal a writer wanting to write by making the counter negative. For that purpose I use a high constant number which I subtract from the thread counter as the thread counter should always be >= 0 for all read operations. If multiple writers are started I only need one to actually do the writing.

The reader part consist of two function as there are multiple ways how the data can be read.

```rust
unsafe fn sign_in() {
    loop {
        let current_active = active_thread_counter.load(Ordering::SeqCst);

        //check if writer is currently writing / waiting to write
        if !(current_active < 0) {
            //try to add as reader
            let before_add = active_thread_counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);

            //if the number was NOT negative before the add we are good to go (no writer waiting)
            if !(before_add < 0) {
                return;
            }
            //writer signed in between first load and the add, so we backtrack and wait for writer to complete
            active_thread_counter.fetch_sub(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
        }

        sleep(Duration::from_nanos(2550));
    }
}

unsafe fn sign_out() {
    active_thread_counter.fetch_sub(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
}
```

While my debugging process consisting of a lot of prints is not 100% consistent regarding multi-threading, it strongly hinted at this lock not working correctly (threads reading while the writer was active).
I would appreciate if you could point a flaw in my thinking here or if you know of a better way to achieve this.

Best Regards,
Lantanar

Comment: [This book](https://marabos.nl/atomics/) may be of great help.

Comment: Have you tried parking_lot's [`RwLock`](https://docs.rs/parking_lot/latest/parking_lot/type.RwLock.html)? That uses [lock_api](https://docs.rs/lock_api/), which you should use in most cases.

Comment: yes my earlier solution was to use parking_lots RwLock, but that trys to allocate memory on drop which causes a crash (calloc call in __cxa_thread_atexit_impl).

Comment: Thx for the book I will take a look at it, but I am unsure if this solves my current problem

Comment: I'd recommend using hexadecimal notation for the huge integer constants, and putting them in a constant.

Comment: Why you chose 2^40 is unclear to me. Wouldn't it make more sense to use 2^63?

Comment: The constant was randomly choosen and its just 2^40 so hex would just be 0x10000000000. Looking equally unreadable for me, or is there any other reason you recommend the formatting?

Comment: i choose 2^40 to have safety in both directions, even if i have 10k reader threads it won't be positive and if i have 10k writers I won't have a negative underflow

Comment: `0x10000000000` is way more readable, being instantly recognizable as a power of 2. `0x100_0000_0000` would be a little better.

Comment: Sharing your test case would help us to reproduce this.

Comment: You really only need two bits for writer queue, since only one writer can hold a lock at a time. One that means "currently writer-locked" and one that means "writer queued, waiting for readers to release". Generally, it looks like most implementations use the least significant bits for these flags.

Comment: Sadly I am unable to reproduce this on a small scale. The problem doesn't occure immediately on program start, but started after a few million calls do the overarching function.

Comment: Yes one bit would be enough, but it is essentally the same as to what I am currently doing (the only difference being a performance gain when multiple writer try to write at the same time), because the flag would have to be in the same atomic as the reader count, else I isn't possible to synchronize them.

Comment: I assume by performance gain you're referring to "If multiple writers are started I only need one to actually do the writing." Can you edit your question to explain exactly what that means? The exact behavior you want is unclear.

Comment: By performance gain I am referring to that he first writer thread doesn't need to wait anymore until all other arriving writer threads have subtractet their value from the active_thread_counter variable to start, as it could just start when the flag was set and all further writers see that the flag was already set after their fetch_or operation.

Comment: You can use a single bit and maintain the same performance gain essentially the same way you are now, but it simplifies things. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a6f94bc513561f4d08d0b1144d8ae8bc)

Comment: Yeah that looks better than my code. So you think that the logic in itself is correct and this is thread safe for reading and writing?

Comment: A constant that fits in a sign-extended 32-bit immediate will make slightly smaller machine code on x86-64, allowing `mov rax, -0x80000000` (7 bytes) instead of 10-byte `movabs r64, imm64` (before `xadd [rdi], rax`).  Since only one writer can take the lock, `lock bts [rdi], 63` (or `31`) would be ideal to use the high bit as a spinlock for writers, except that doesn't check the other bits.  So really we'd want `fetch_or` to set the high bit and retrieve the old value to detect writers, which on x86-64 requires a `lock cmpxchg` retry loop. :/

Comment: Or just `lock bts` to establish which writer won the race, and then reload to spin-wait until the reader count drops to zero.  It costs an extra reload in the no-contention fast path which you avoid by using a large constant for `lock xadd`, so that's fun.  I didn't check your logic, but if you do it right, this should work for a readers/writers spinlock.  And depending what you do while spinning, could fall back to OS-assisted sleep/wake.